# Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'ArrayList'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm working on a program for class and I get the error "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'ArrayList' " and also "expected initializer before 'ArrayList' ". I've looked at several different questions with similar error messages but nothing seemed to help.

Relevant Code:

**arraylist.h**

```
template <typename T>
class ArrayList
{ 
private:  
  //some member variables here                          
public:
  //member functions, including:
  T& operator[](int i);
  const T& operator[](int i) const;
```

**arraylist.hpp**

```
template<class T> &T ArrayList<T>::operator[](int i)   //first error message here 
{
  if(i < 0 || i > m_size)
    return m_errobj;
  else
    return m_data[i];
}

template<class T> const &T ArrayList<T>::operator[](int i) const  //second error message here
{
  if (i < 0 || i > m_size)
    return m_errobj;
  else
    return m_data[i];
}
```

It should be noted that I can't alter the .h file as it was provided by the professor. I'm using g++ compiler. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, it's my first question... be gentle :)

Comment: Change the return types to `T&` and `const T&` respectively. Prefix `&` is the address-of operator, which you presumably know because you've got it right in the template declaration.

Comment: Ugh... I knew it was something obvious that I just wasn't seeing. Thank you!